# How to avoid conflict on a CAN bus when sending data frames with the same frame id?

Tags: can-bus

Usually, a remote frame is sent to require data from another node, which sends a corresponding data frame with the same identifier later. But when both of the nodes are sending a data frame, how to avoid the bus conflict?

For example, node A sends a data frame  to node B, e.g., move 10mm forward, then node B returns a data frame to node A when the motion is completed. So that both of the messages have the same data and the identifiers are same.

**Update**

Currently the node id is assigned to an entire PCB, which contains mulitple components like sensors and motors. According to [Lundin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55608899/5658049)'s post, I realize that it's impossible to distinguish these components. There is a high possibility to lead to bit error, when sending messages to a mortor, and meanwhile get a response message from sensors, for example. No arbitration takes effect in this case. So, are the following points the best practices?

1. Each of the sensor or motor should be defined as a node with a unique identifier. But it seems not convenient to move components between different PCBs, since the filters of the corresponding PCBs should be updated every time.
2. Each of the PCB should define more filters to accept all the identifiers of the nodes on it.
3. ONLY use remote frame to require data from sensor.

Comment: You probably already know, but one idea is to note use all bits of the CAN-ID as noide-id, [as CANopen does](https://www.csselectronics.com/screen/page/canopen-tutorial-simple-intro/language/en#canopen-communication-basics). This way bus arbitration could happen within a node. It seems strange not to use bus arbitration for this use-case.

Comment: CANopen protocol is really great. In fact, I realy want the bus arbitration to be involved, but had no idea how to do that. CANopen should be the best solution, but might require some modifications to adapt to my project, where the amount of function codes is more than node ids. I was trying to move function code from the data field to the frame id, like `node id + function code`, but not so confident to do that, and CANopen seems more reasonable and sophisticated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem as long as they never send at the same time. If you implement a handshaking scheme like the one you describe, where only one node is allowed to send data at a time, it will work fine.

Otherwise it is common to use node id to distinguish between nodes. For example if your data has identifier `0x100`, then node A can send id `0x100` and node B id `0x101`. The receiver can then treat these the same.

Comment: How to allow only one node to send data at a time? Wait until an expected message received within a reasonable time? I will add an update later with more details. Thank you!

Comment: I think even sending at different times is problematic (except with a "mutex-like" handshake, which has its own problems). If the bus is busy with a burst of lower IDs both senders will wait (lose arbitration) until it is free, and then both will send (win arbitration) exactly at the same time.

Comment: When designing a higher layer CAN bus protocol, you must have real-time specifications of when messages shall be sent. Everything else is quackery.

Comment: I think Lundin wants to say that messages with the same frame id should be well-considered and transmitted in pre-defined order, like handshake. It should be a bug of the system when there are more than one this type of messages sent at a time. btw, what kind of problems does mutex-like handshake implied?